# In Data.Data, why does gmapM take a Monad rather than an applicative?

Tags: haskell

`gmapM` seems like the obvious candidate for writing a generic traversal based on `Data.Data`, for instance, if one wants to implement `MonoTraversable`. The only hiccup is that it takes a `Monad` rather than an `Applicative`. Why is that? Also, is there a similar function to `fmapM` with weaker assumptions?

Comment: `Data.Data` is quite outdated anyway. GHC Generics are the current type-safe, performant and modular solution for generic programming.

Comment: I usually prefer `GHC.Generics` too. It does get verbose though. I find it surprising how simple (or at least concise) `Data.Data` solutions can be. I wonder if `Data.Data` could be made faster with a lot of rewrite rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a historical detail from before implementing the Monad-Applicative proposal.

I can define both the `gmapM` default and the instance for lists in terms of `Applicative`.

```
gmapM :: forall m a. (Data a, Applicative m) => (forall d. Data d => d -> m d) -> a -> m a
gmapM f = gfoldl k pure
  where
    k :: Data d => m (d -> b) -> d -> m b
    k c x = c <*> f x

-- instance Data a => Data [a] where ...
gmapMlist :: forall m a. (Data a, Applicative m) => (forall d. Data d => d -> m d) -> [a] -> m [a]
gmapMlist _   []     = pure []
gmapMlist f   (x:xs) = (:) <$> f x <*> f xs
```